# Block screen when refreshing data

Tags: web-app, refresh, api

I have a web app with a grid with some data. The grid refresh every 1 minute, the problem is that the API I am calling takes more or less 2 seconds to retrieve the information. To avoid the user make another call to the API (for example changing the filter so the grid must refresh with the user selected filter) I block the screen with a spinner and a loading bar.

Is this the correct way to do it? Or its better not to show the loading bar and not block the screen? Maybe postpone the new call?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, **make the user feel they are the one in control**.

It's usually best to have an asynchronous behaviour and not block the user because of a *system* behaviour.

Make your update API call every minute, but in the background and don't block the user. If the *user's actions* require an interim change, either cancel or ignore the original update data and trigger a new API call, and perhaps reset the minute timer so that another change doesn't happen too soon.

**Users like to be in control.** They are much happier to have the display update when *they* want, but much less happy to have the display update when they didn't trigger it themselves, especially if it involves a blocking aspect.

Typically there is often a way for the user to change the time between updates (including the *never* option), but I appreciate that may not always make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that a user has to wait every minute for 2 seconds, so that new data come in. How will this user feel? Annoyed? Frustrated? Mad with the application? All of these together?

Personally, I like the solutions that give an immediate feedback to the user, such as twitter:

[image: Twitter]

Then the user knows that something new has come in and they can choose when to load or refresh. As for the case that the user has selected a filter, ideally the new data should be filtered as well according to the user's already-made selection.